# Why doesn't it show many Taxi Drivers waiting at the harbour?

Tags: plot-explanation, triangle

In the movie *Triangle*, since the same thing happens again and again, bodies of Sally, many written copies, bodies of crashed sea gulls are found in the same place.

In the climax, the taxi driver is saying that he will be waiting in the harbour for her return. So when the loop restarts, then there must another driver entering the harbour shore and waiting on the shore for Jess's return. So when this iteration continues, there must be multiple drivers waiting on the shore

Why doesn't the movie show that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**He may have given up, or might be a mythological figure from the underworld.**

It's possible that the driver assumed she was going to go up to the boat, talk to people, then come back.  So far, we have no indication that she told him she was going on a cruise.  Upon seeing her board the boat, or after waiting for a long time, **he may have given up** on it and left without his money.  He could visit the harbor shop, or some other means to try and figure out who she was for money collection purposes.

Another theory is that she is trapped in an underworld.  Note how they mention Sisyphus in detail aboard the cruise ship.  Sisyphus was eternally punished in the underworld for his actions.  It could be said that Jess was condemned by the gods for striking her son out of anger, killed in the car crash, and that the **taxi driver is Hades** (or more likely Charon, since he is ferrying her to her punishment).  He also is surprisingly casual about removing a grief stricken mother from the car crash, and says he expects her to come back in a knowing manner.  It seems like something is wrong with this guy.

Therefore, you would not have multiple copies since the driver either leaves in each iteration, or is an architect of the loops unconstrained by the repetition.

Comment: Well said I accept your view

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question, and possibly a detail the writer chose to omit as it would have caused too much suspicion.  On the other hand, many of the details were slightly different during the loop.  That is to say, not everything happened *exactly* the same, but the outcomes were the same.  It's also possible that other drivers had been called away, or a different mode of transportation was used.  I don't think we're ever going to know either way until that question is posed to the person who wrote the movie.

Comment: Yeah.. I accept the possibility of different modes of transportation